# A condition in an array, Python

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I have an array say "x" of 100 values ranging from 0 to 9. I have to use this "x" in a formula for finding a component "sigma". But there are three conditions for finding "sigma", which are, **while x<1, sigma = formula, while x=1, sigma = formula** and **while x>1, sigma = formula**

I need to write a Python code that takes all values of x<1 and apply it to **"sigma"**, and all values of x= 1 and so on and apply it to **"sigma"** to get **"sigma" (an array of the same length, i.e 100 values**

How can I do it?

My attempt so far is:

```
a1 = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/(x**2-1)
b1 = (2/(np.sqrt(1-x**2)))
c1 = np.arctanh(np.sqrt((1-x)/(1+x)))

a2 = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/(1-x**2)
b2 = 2/(np.sqrt(x**2-1))
c2 = np.arctan(np.sqrt((x-1)/(1+x)))


#finding sigma(x)

for i in x:
    if i<1:
        sigma = a1*(1-(b1*c1))
    elif i == 1:
        sigma = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/3
    elif i>1:
        sigma = a2*(1-(b2*c2))
```

The problem is, if you can see in my formula for a1,b1,c1 and a2,b2,c2, there is x involved. So I need to apply the conditions for x here as well

Comment: This is python.. **lists**. Also, can you show us your attempts so far? Input and output?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem with an example? Or this question might get closed for being not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with boolean item assignment (for numpy arrays):

```
sigma = np.empty(x.shape)
sigma[x<1] = a1*(1-(b1*c1))
sigma[x==1] = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/3
sigma[x>1] = a2*(1-(b2*c2))
```

Comment: An alternative idiom is `sigma = np.empty_like(x)`

Comment: @heltonbiker -- Ahh yes, I never remember that one ;-), although that *might* give the wrong type if the original array is integers.

Comment: @mgilson the problem is, if you can see in my formula for a1,b1 and c1 , there is x. So I need to apply the conditions there as well

Comment: @srivatsan -- Ahh, those are arrays.  in that case, you'd do something  like `sigma[x<1] = (a1*(1-b1*c1))[x<1]`

Comment: @mgilson when I try your above method I am getting ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: What is the shape of `a1`, `b1` ... `c2` and `sigma`?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sigma = x
for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    a1 = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/(xi**2-1)
    b1 = (2/(np.sqrt(1-xi**2)))
    c1 = np.arctanh(np.sqrt((1-xi)/(1+xi)))

    a2 = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/(1-xi**2)
    b2 = 2/(np.sqrt(xi**2-1))
    c2 = np.arctan(np.sqrt((xi-1)/(1+xi)))

    if xi<1:
        sigma[i] = a1*(1-(b1*c1))
    elif xi == 1:
        sigma[i] = (2*delta_c*rho_0*r_s)/3
    elif xi>1:
        sigma[i] = a2*(1-(b2*c2))
```

Comment: The problem is, if you can see in my formula for a1,b1 and c1 , there is x. So I need to apply the conditions for x here as well

Comment: So you're starting with an n x 3 array and you want to end up with another n x 3 array?

Comment: No, I have just split the formula into a1,b1 and c1 for convenience. If you can see the final formula for sigma, it is nothing but a1*(1-(b1*c1)), a2*(1-(b2*c2)) according to the condition of x